# Wd.var not giving results as expected in R

Tags: r

```
> wt.var(c(1,8,9),c(0.5,0.25,0.25))
[1] 22.7
> 0.5*(1-6)^2+0.25*(8-6)^2+0.25*(9-6)^2
[1] 15.75
> 0.5*(1-4.75)^2+0.25*(8-4.5)^2+0.25*(9-4.75)^2 
[1] 14.60938
```

I am using the wt.var function in the SDMTools package to compute weighted variance. I tried looking for documentation online and found cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SDMTools/SDMTools.pdf online. There is a link directing to http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Weighted-Samples.htmland. However, the page doesn't exist. Why is there a discrepancy in the weighted variance calc? The third line with 4.75 is the weighted mean. But it doesnt look like wt.var uses that either.

Answer (score 1):

See formula [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Weighted_sample_variance) in Wikipedia:

```
x1<-c(1,8,9)
w1<-c(0.5,0.25,0.25)
wt.mean<-sum(x1*w1)/sum(w1)
wt.var<-(sum(w1)/(sum(w1)^2-sum(w1^2)))*(sum(w1*(x1-wt.mean)^2))
wt.var
[1] 22.7
```